# MultiThreading in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to run two threads in parallel. But unfortunately , it sometime works sometime not. Here is my code

```
 let firstQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)
 let secondQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue2", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)
//let firstQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1", qos: DispatchQoS.default , attributes: .concurrent)

    firstQueue.async {
        for i in 0..<10 {
            print("", i)
        }
    }


    secondQueue.async {
        for i in 20..<30 {
            print("⚪️", i)
        }
    }
```

I have tried different everything but not achieve perfect parallelism.
First Time Output: `0
⚪️ 20
 1
⚪️ 21
 2
⚪️ 22
 3
⚪️ 23
 4
⚪️ 24
 5
⚪️ 25
 6
⚪️ 26
 7
⚪️ 27
 8
⚪️ 28
 9
⚪️ 29`

SecondTime Output :

0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
⚪️ 20
⚪️ 21
⚪️ 22
⚪️ 23
⚪️ 24
⚪️ 25
⚪️ 26
⚪️ 27
⚪️ 28
⚪️ 29

Comment: What are you expecting from Queue's Async operation?

Comment: I am expecting FirstOutput.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The point of multithreading is that operations will be done parallel and independent from one another. That does not guaranty any order at all, there is no synchronization, no nothing. If you need to have things synchronized then you will need to use a single thread or use a third thread that dispatches work:

```
func foo() {
    let firstQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1")
    let secondQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue2")

    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queueMain")

    var firstQueueOperationsCount: Int = 10
    var secondQueueOperationsCount: Int = 10

    func performOperations() {
        guard max(firstQueueOperationsCount, secondQueueOperationsCount) > 0 else {
            return
        }
        mainQueue.async {
            if firstQueueOperationsCount > secondQueueOperationsCount {
               firstQueueOperationsCount -= 1
                firstQueue.async {
                    print("")
                    performOperations()
                }
            } else {
                secondQueueOperationsCount -= 1
                secondQueue.async {
                    print("⚪️")
                    performOperations()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    performOperations()
}
```

There are many ways on how to serialize tasks dispatched on multiple threads and this being just one of them. You might try searching/reading toward that direction but just be clear: What you seem to expect from multithreading is NOT WHAT MULTITHREADING IS. It does not work this way and it does not supposed to work this way. How they do work is how we want it to work.

If you have a more specific situation I am sure community here may help you identify a good approach to solve it. But from what you have written the result is not multithreading but:

```
for i in 0..<10 {
    print("")
    print("⚪️")
}
```

It might be dispatched on another thread but that really makes no difference.

Comment: Very Nice Explanation. Thank You so much. I just need one more help. I am calling my two callback func instead of  print("⚪️") and print("").  But the thing is that Only second completion handler work both times.

Comment: @SaadullahOffice What do you mean "works both times"? Please be more descriptive in what you are doing, what is your expected result and what is your current result.

Comment: Instead of print("") and print("⚪️") I want my speedTest function to call in both queues with 2 different urls and give me speedResult in completion block of respective completion block function called in each queue. Is this Possible ? Or let me know if you need more information i will post a file with description

Comment: @SaadullahOffice it seems completely possible. If I understand correctly a speed test will call a closure when done which should than call `performOperations()` which will then start the next operation. Which part is not working or what am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

Your code works well, but the thing you should know is that, you haven't any choice to decide which part of your code execute first, and since your code is just printing a character and its a light job to do for cpu you see some times your characters printing ordered and some times unordered. Try to give some more heavy job to cpu and then see the results!

Comment: Ohh Thats nice. Let me do some heavy work. Can you tell me that calling "Call back functions" in both queues works fine ?

Comment: Do you mean using for statement?

Comment: `TestDownload.sharedInstance.testDownloadSpeedWithTimout(timeout: 10.0, url: self.urlArr[0]) { (speed, error) in
                            
                            print("Download Speed0:", speed ?? "NA")
                            print("Speed Test Error0:", error ?? "NA")
                            
                            self.speedValue.append(speed!)
                            self.concurentHit += 1
                            //self.speedUpload.text = "\(speeds!)"
                            
                            
         
                        }`

Comment: This will be the code iam using in both async tasks with different url but completion handler only jumps in 2nd task

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup), also you should read more about GCD, the code below work as expected and it will fix your issue

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let firstQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)
let secondQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue2", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)

firstQueue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        print("", i)
    }
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

secondQueue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    for i in 20..<30 {
        print("⚪️", i)
    }
}
```

the output always will be like this   0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
⚪️ 20
⚪️ 21
⚪️ 22
⚪️ 23
⚪️ 24
⚪️ 25
⚪️ 26
⚪️ 27
⚪️ 28
⚪️ 29